# Eval function is not working and error says it must be a string - Python

Tags: python

I just don't know what to do...

[image: my code]

[image: error]

Comment: what python version are you using? and don't post pictures of code or errors, provide those as properly formatted text

Comment: If all you want to do is add input  + 3 you can just do `x = int(input("Adds 3"))` if you have the right version

Comment: in Python2 (which you shouldn't be using but based on the error it is what you are using) `input` already does the evaluation so just do `x = input('heyy: ')`

Comment: Don’t use Python 2, don’t use `eval`. If you have to use Python 2, the correct code is `x = int(raw_input("heyy: "))`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try using int

```
x = int(input("Enter an integer : "))
print(x+3)
```

using eval:

> Python eval() function parse the expression argument and evaluate it
> as a python expression and runs python expression(code) within the
> program.

```
x = int(input("Enter the value : "))
print(eval(f"x+{3}"))
```

## output :

```
$ python3 test.py
Enter the value : 5
8
```

Comment: for them it would work as simply `x = input('hey: ')`

Answer (score -1):

The `eval()` built-in function is for executing things that are in a string format.

To fix the error you're getting, either remove `eval()` or put `input("heyy: ")` in quotes:

```py
x = eval("input(\"heyy: \")")
```

(The backslashes before quote marks are for escaping the quote, otherwise the quote mark in the string in input() would close the quote that you've opened first)

Also, both the `eval()` and `input()` functions would return a string, you need to convert it to an integer to add 5 onto it:

```
x = int(x)
```

Comment: `eval` wouldn't necessarily return a string nor would `input` in Python2, your first 2 suggested solutions would work tho (if OP uses Python2)

Comment: @Matiiss `eval()` returns whatever the string passed to it would return. Also, as the OP used parentheses to print something, we can understand that it's not Python 2. So, it's necessary to convert to integer.

Comment: both statements are incorrect, [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) _returns the result of the evaluated expression_, parentheses can be used in Python2 too and OP uses Python2 based on the exception they get which they wouldn't get in Python3

Comment: I said the same thing, I just don't know those terms like (evaluated expression) so I had to use a poor language to express what I mean. Though, I didn't know the second thing.

Comment: that was taken from documentation... parentheses are just parentheses, usually they are used for calling a function but they can also be used for grouping things, creating tuples and some other things probably, in OP's case it is the same as using parentheses with `return` (sth like `return (value1, value2)` (which is not necessary)), it is just a keyword there, unlike in Python3 where it is a function

Comment: I see, thanks for info.